# How to open pdf with JavaScript/vue

Tags: javascript, java, typescript, spring-boot, vue.js

I have a application generated with jhipster and vue as admin dashboard. My Java code is connecting to Dropbox downloading images and converting them to pdf and saving them to a folder at the same level like src.

What I want to try now is to download open the pdf in a new tab with a button click. But I am getting the following error:

```
Can not GET /generatedPdf/toBePrintedPdf
```

My code looks like this:

```
openPdf(){
    window.open("generatedPdf/toBePrintedPdf.pdf", "_blank");
    return false;
}
```

This is the vue part:

```
<b-button v-on:click="openPdf" variant="primary">open pdf</b-button>
```

Can someone help me find my error?

Edit:

Sorry for the late edit it was a hard week with a lot of work for me. I will now send the folder structure as a picture, if there are any other question feel free to ask. The folder called 'generatedPdf' contains the pdf and the marked component is from where I try to open the pdf. Sadly I had to take picture from my phone sorry for that.

[image: Folder structure]

Comment: Looks like the pdf is not actually there. Does it work if you manually enter the url in your browser?

Comment: No but I can open the pdf if I click on it via the file explorer or through intellj.

Comment: So I thought it is a valid pdf.

Comment: What could the problem be? I just tested with a pdf from my downloads folder without a connection to my project but it does not open either

Comment: Where are the pdfs, relative to the web server root?

Comment: They are in the root at the most top layer in the project same level as Pom.XML and package.json I can sent a picture if that helps

Comment: Yes, please [edit] your question and show that.

Comment: Sorry for the late replt it was a long week with a lot of things to do. I just uploaded my folder structure.

Comment: How are you deploying this (I mean, with maven? gradle?)? Depending on that you'd need to tell whatever builds the project where to put the `generatedPdf` folder in the deployed artifact, which I guess should be under `resources` but I'm not sure.

Comment: For my backend (spring boot) I use maven. And for my frontend (Vue) I am using npm

Comment: My backend is connecting to dropbox and downloading the images and then combining them to pdf